# List Filenames and Date

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, dos, command-prompt

We have a file repository containing code files `*.sql; *.xep; *.dll; *.aspx; *.gif` that you are going to submit to Production pretty soon. In this repository we have the main folders which contain the most recent code files to go to PROD, but we also have all the Change Folders that where submitted to PRE-PROD with code. You can see the main repository structure in the image below:

[image]

The protocol is that whenever we submit something to PRE-PROD, we e create a Change Folder, place it in the main repository, and also update the main folders, but sometimes we forget to do the second part.
What i was trying to do in a automated way is: if there is a file with the same name in the main folder and the change folder they need the have the same modified date day (at least), this specific crossing i could easily do in Excel or even SQL.
So, finally :P , what i needed help in, is getting into a csv fileformat (';' separating values, and '\n' separating rows), all the `*.sql; *.xep; *.dll; *.aspx; *.gif` from the main repository directory and sub-directories.

So far I i have tested with this dos commands:

```
dir *.sql *.xep *.aspx *.dll *.gif /s /a:-D>listWithDate.txt
```

this one gets me a list, ie: listWithDate.txt, that a i have formated in this fashion:

```
2012/03/19[2sapces]14:27[Nspaces]4.006[1space][filename]
2012/03/19[2sapces]14:27[Nspaces]10.006[1space][filename]
```

So needed help in on of the two:

*batch to list Filenames and Date to a csv formated file*

or

*batch to format the listWithDate.txt into a csv formated file*

Many thanks in advance ;)

Comment: @BaliC why did you roll back the image inline change?

Comment: Basically, you want to generate a CSV using the list, if I am right?

Comment: @adarshr I was editing at the same as you, and mine had more editing so I think it took precedence over yours.

Comment: @BaliC Not a problem, I have fixed now. By the way, it was David who was editing then. Not me.

Comment: @adarshr Cool, ah yeah, I didn't realise :)

Comment: tks for the editing fellows :)
@adarshr yes basically that, just need 2 cols, Date Modified, and File Name.

Comment: Solved, i just need to open the txt file with excel :P

Comment: Please do not add spam like `[SOLVED]` to your question title.

Comment: @CodyGray - You must have an odd definition of SPAM unlike any other I've seen. I assume you would prefer that the OP post the answer as an answer and then accept the answer when possible.

Comment: @dbenham: I don't think it's particularly odd. Spam is often used to refer to unwanted or excess "noise" online, which is precisely what this is. Yes, if you have arrived at a solution different from one of those already posted by someone else, you should post that as an answer and accept it. If one of the answers posted was instrumental in arriving at a solution, you should accept that answer. If it requires more information, you should edit it to include any additional details, and then accept it. It serves absolutely no purpose whatsoever to add `[SOLVED]` to the *title* of a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following one-liner will output file timestamps (as single units), file sizes (in bytes), and file names as a CSV row set:

```
>csvfile.txt (FOR %R IN (*.sql *.xep *.aspx *.dll *.gif) DO @ECHO "%~tR";%~zR;"%~nxR")
```

Note: this is supposed to be run directly from the command prompt. If you wish to put this in a batch script, double every `%` character.

Comment: This is really useful. But i am trying to get file name by filtering files by current date. If you have any idea, it will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

hmm i think that this might work:

```
    @echo off
    echo.
    if exist newfile.csv del newfile.csv
    for /f "tokens=1-4* delims= " %%a in (listWithDate.txt) do (
        rem %%a is date %%b is time, %%c is filesize, %%d is filename
        rem use %%b or %%c as needed
        echo %%d, %%a >> newfile.csv
    )
```

that should generate the file you are looking for, let me know if this works for you

Comment: you could also substitute this: (listWithDate.txt) with this ('dir *.sql *.xep *.aspx *.dll *.gif /s /a:-D'), that way you are not even generating the listwithdate.txt file.